# organize horizontal data to vertical data in excel

Tags: excel

Need some help with excel having complexity of dates are structured in horizontal manner. Process is, new data are added horizontally & vertically, where the visit code are added vertically while dates are added horizontally, although other fields are fixed-structured vertically as well.

What i am trying to achieve is to keep all data in vertical, i.e. dates are structured vertically even the visits & other fields are duplicating. In this way, it is easier to generate a pivot.

Otherwise, please advise other way as objective is to make a simple pivot to count the visits filtering by dates.

I hope I explained my case clearly & really need support badly.

Thanks.

Baluloi

[worksheet printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZAaR.jpg)

Comment: Please update your question with a small example of input data and expected results.

Comment: I think it is better to ask the questioner to improve the question, tell him what is missing or edit it yourself to improve it rather than to just down vote it. After all it is his first question.

Comment: Apologies @Gary's Student, I have attached the screenshot of my worksheet. Apparently, this is the best explanation & question at the same time that i could. Most of what i found is Transpose method, but my requirement is a bit different. I hope what i attached could clear it out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Baluloi you can simply copy your data and before pasting it in its destination, right click and then click [transpose](/questions/tagged/transpose).  This function in excel will take your top record and past it at the farthest point to the left reading & pasting left to right.

Comment: Thank you z33Will, but the Transpose method does not actually fit to my requirement. I have attached screenshot of my worksheet as reference, what I am trying to achieve an easy way (programmed) to place the entire data column (which in this case is date field) to bottom where questions field can be duplicated, it will appear that date field will be arrange in 1 column (col. G). I hope i elaborated it clearly. Thanks.